# calling a java class method in another class

Tags: java, web-services, fax

Hi I have below Java Class for Sending Fax from Java

```
package oracle.apps.print;

import com.softlinx.replixfax.*;

import javax.xml.ws.*;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import java.io.File;

public class Fax {

    public void SendFax(String Filepath, String faxno) {
        try {


            ReplixFaxService service = new ReplixFaxService();
            ReplixFaxPort port = service.getReplixFaxPort();
            ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "admin");
            //            ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"https://api.rpxfax.com/softlinx/replixfax/wsapi");
            ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                                                            "https://api.rpxtest.com:9999/softlinx/replixfax/wsapi");


            Authentication auth = new Authentication();
            auth.setLogin("user");
            String password = "pwd";

            auth.setPassword(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(password.getBytes()));
            auth.setRealm("MTBC");
            auth.setPasswordSecurity("base64");


            SendFaxInput sendFaxInput = new SendFaxInput();
            sendFaxInput.setAuthentication(auth);

            FaxRecipient recipient = new FaxRecipient();
            recipient.setFaxNumber(faxno.toString());

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            File f = new File(Filepath.toString());
            attachment.setFileName(f.getName());

            Path path = Paths.get(Filepath.toString());
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            attachment.setAttachmentContent(data);

            sendFaxInput.getFaxRecipient().add(recipient);
            sendFaxInput.getAttachment().add(attachment);

            SendFaxOutput result = port.sendFax(sendFaxInput);
            System.out.println("Status Code= " + result.getRequestStatus().getStatusCode());

            if (result.getFaxInfo() != null) {
                System.out.println("Fax ID = " + result.getFaxInfo().get(0).getFaxId());

            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

I am compiling this class like this

```
javac -cp .;./commons-codec-1.10.jar Fax.java
```

However Compiling of both classes is fine no error at compile time

when i call the method `Fax` in another class (XXEmail) like this

```
package oracle.apps.print;


public class XXEmail implements JavaConcurrentProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Fax mtbcfax = new Fax();
            mtbcfax.SendFax("E:\\csv_svb\\3010218.pdf", "173224xxxx");
            out.writeln("Fax Sent Successfully");

        } catch (Exception i) {
            log.writeln("Error while Sending Fax " + i.getMessage(), LogFile.STATEMENT);
        } finally {
            log.writeln("Error while Sending Fax ");
        }

    }
}
```

It always goes to Finally block with out showing any error

How can i call this method so it should return with success code or exception

Comment: `"It always goes to Finally block with out showing any error"` -- **What** finally block? Your posted code shows no finally block. What have you done to try to debug this?

Comment: After exception block

Comment: Please clarify because you're still not making sense. Again your posted code shows **no** finally block. None. So what are you talking about?

Comment: i have edited the code how i calling the method , please check this

Comment: That finally block will always be called, no matter if the code works as behaved or if an exception has been called, and so the fact that the finally code is run tells you nothing

Comment: so what may the problem ? am i doing right or wrong with calling of methods

Comment: Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2

Comment: I am aware of catch & Finally block , i just want to know where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to:
Comment all lines in the SendFax function and add only a log:

```
public void SendFax(String Filepath, String faxno) {
   out.writeln("No problem here");
}
```

Now start the program and see if the function is correctly called or not.
If It is correctly called, so probably the arguments you send are wrong.

Comment: As you suggested i already tried with small calculation of numbers it works fine with Integers

Comment: This is strange, I'm sorry but I don't know how to help you :/ My suggest is to do a good debugging operation to understand where the program goes in error.

Comment: okay i got a bit issue , if i remove the `package oracle.apps.print;` from Fax class it runs successfully itself and send fax also , can you tell me how can i still call this class in another class in package `package oracle.apps.print;`